# unable to access my rails application using Public IP of my Ubuntu server in a browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

Excuse me for the noob question.

I have a Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-63-generic x86_64) server and my public IP is something like 183.xx.xxx.xx (curl -4 icanhazip.com).I am running my rails app using the command:

```
rails s -b0.0.0.0 -p3002
```

and puma server has started successfully

```
    => Booting Puma
    => Rails 5.0.3 application starting in development on http://localhost:3002
    => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
    Puma starting in single mode...
    * Version 3.9.1 (ruby 2.4.0-p0), codename: Private Caller
    * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
    * Environment: development
    * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3002
    Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

I tried to access my app in the browser using:

```
 http://183.xx.xxx.xx:3002
```

I am getting

```
This site can’t be reached
172.xx.xxx.xx took too long to respond.
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

**netstat -plnt**

```
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:45109           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3002            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25689/0.0.0.0:3002)
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6010          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

A process is running with a pid 25689

Any help is highly Appreciate.Thanks in Advance!

Comment: you sure using proper ip verify `ifconfig`

Comment: why do you want to access your rails app via the port? just configure it with a web server. like: apache2 or Nginx

Comment: @Farhan ,Thanks you for your response.I am sure using the correct public IP.

Comment: @hgsongra, I  have various versions of my app, so i want to run them all for a temporary purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
rails s -b 192.168.1.23 -p 3000
```

then 
run

```
192.168.1.23:3000
```

Comment: @Dhanesh, Thank you for your answer.I tried with rails s -b 183.xx.xxx.xx -p3002 as you suggested, but I am getting (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL).

Answer (score 0):

You should edit your `/etc/hosts` file for `0.0.0.0` to *point to your public ip(183.xx.xxx.xx)*

***Tested:***

```
#/etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   pavan
0.0.0.0     192.xxx.x.xxx #my ip
```

Now I ran the rails server with `rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3002` and I can access it with my IP *(192.xxx.x.xxx:3002)*

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.I have added 0.0.0.0 183.xx.xxx.xx in  /etc/hosts file.But still i could not access the app in my browser.My code was in /var/www folder of the 183.xx.xxx.xx server.

Answer (score 0):

For booting your server on public IP first you need to find-out your public ip which can be done by running command on Ubuntu terminal `ifconfig`

copy the ip mentioned under eth0 key as:

`eth0      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 
          inet addr:192.168.X.XXX`

For booting your rails server on this public Ip you have to run command:

```
rails s -b PUBLIC_IP_OF_SYSTEM -p PORT_TO_BOOT_ON
```

in your case it would be like:

```
rails s -b 183.xx.xxx.xx -p 3002
```